# Which function of core location framework gets called when user changes its current location?

Tags: iphone, ios5, gps, xcode4.2, core-location

I am using core location framework inside my app i want to ask that which function of core location framework get called when user changes its current location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method gets called when a new location is available. oldLocation may be nil if there is    no previous location  available.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
        didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
        fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation;
```

Comment: Thanks Mudit and how can i change the current location in iphone 4s for testing this function? I have to send the updated location on server by hitting the specific url inside this method.

Comment: You can get the newLocation latitude and longitude inside this function  using newLocation.coordinate.latitude and newLocation.coordinate.longitude.check [this](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_iOS_5_iPhone_Location_Application)

Comment: will this function automatically called when we move to a large distance from current location and also app is running on background? or have i need to set the CLLocation object to nil every time for getting newLocation?

Comment: You will have to set the delegate property of CLLocationManager, then it will call and in background also  it will call automatically.for move to large distance you will have to set the desiredAccuracy property of CLLocationManager.then it wiil automatically update the newLocation and you will get the new Coordinate through newLocation.

Comment: Thanks Mudit and one more question is will i have need to set the CLLocation object to nil every time for getting newLocation?